# Colophon for an R book

Tags: r, package, knitr

At the end of an R book, I'd like to show the versions of main R packages used to compile the book.  I'm wondering if there is anything I could do better than just use `sessionInfo()` in a chunk, e.g.,

```
\section*{Colophon}
This book was produced using \Sexpr{R.version.string}, 
\pkg{knitr} (\Sexpr{packageDescription("knitr")[["Version"]]})
and other package versions listed below.

<<session-info, size='footnotesize',R.options=list(width=90)>>=
print(sessionInfo(), locale = FALSE)
@
```

In particular, `sessionInfo()` lists all packages loaded indirectly as well as those loaded directly.

Answer (score 3):

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
p = devtools::loaded_packages()
p$version =   unlist(lapply(p$package, function(x) as.character(packageVersion(x))))
kable(p[order(p$package),], row.names=FALSE)
```
````

If you do not have devtools installed, steal the code from `loaded_packages`.

Answer (score 2):

This will give a comma separated list of the packages loaded into the current session:

```
pkgs <- sort(sub("package:", "", grep("package:", search(), value = TRUE)));
toString(Map(function(p) sprintf("%s (%s)", p, packageVersion(p)), pkgs))
```

giving this string which you can insert by placing the code above in a `\Sexpr`:

```
[1] "base (3.2.0), datasets (3.2.0), graphics (3.2.0), grDevices (3.2.0), methods (3.2.0), stats (3.2.0), utils (3.2.0)"
```

Only core R functions are used in this code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to list all packages loaded (base packages, dependencies) in the current session, so I came up with a better solution for my needs. Maybe this will be useful to someone else.

1. Find all packages explicitly loaded via `library()` in the .Rnw files for the book.
2. Use `devtools:::package_info()` for formatting

For (1.), I used the following pipe of shell commands, all standard except for my trusty `tcgrep` perl script that find strings in files recursively

```
tcgrep -E Rnw '^library(.*)' . \
     | grep '/ch'  \ 
     | perl -p -e 's/^.*://; s/\s*#.*//' \ 
     | perl -p -e 's/library\(([\w\d]+)\)/"$1"/g; s/;/, /' \
     | sort -u | perl -p -e 's/\n/, /' > packages-used.R
```

This gave me

```
packages <- c(
"AER", "ca", "car", "colorspace", "corrplot", "countreg", "directlabels", "effects", "ggparallel", "ggplot2", "ggtern", "gmodels", "gnm", "gpairs", "heplots", "Lahman", "lattice", "lmtest", "logmult", "MASS", "MASS",  "countreg", "mgcv", "nnet", "plyr", "pscl", "RColorBrewer", "reshape2", "rms", "rsm", "sandwich", "splines", "UBbipl", "vcd", "vcdExtra", "VGAM", "xtable")
```

Then for (2.),

```
library(devtools)
pkg_info <- devtools:::package_info(packages)
# clean up unwanted
pkg_info$source <- sub(" \\(R.*\\)", "", pkg_info$source)
pkg_info <- pkg_info[,-2]

pkg_info
```

I like the result because it also identifies non-CRAN (development version) packages. I could also format this with `kable`:

```
> pkg_info
 package      version   date       source 
 AER          1.2-3     2015-02-24 CRAN   
 ca           0.60      2015-03-01 R-Forge
 car          2.0-25    2015-03-03 R-Forge
 colorspace   1.2-6     2015-03-11 CRAN   
 corrplot     0.73      2013-10-15 CRAN   
 countreg     0.1-2     2014-10-17 R-Forge
 directlabels 2013.6.15 2013-07-23 CRAN   
 effects      3.0-4     2015-03-22 R-Forge
 ggparallel   0.1.1     2012-09-09 CRAN   
 ggplot2      1.0.1     2015-03-17 CRAN   
 ggtern       1.0.5.0   2015-04-15 CRAN   
 gmodels      2.15.4.1  2013-09-21 CRAN   
 gnm          1.0-8     2015-04-22 CRAN   
 gpairs       1.2       2014-03-09 CRAN   
 heplots      1.0-15    2015-04-18 CRAN   
 Lahman       3.0-1     2014-09-13 CRAN   
 lattice      0.20-31   2015-03-30 CRAN   
 lmtest       0.9-33    2014-01-23 CRAN   
 logmult      0.6.2     2015-04-22 CRAN   
 MASS         7.3-40    2015-03-21 CRAN   
 mgcv         1.8-6     2015-03-31 CRAN   
 nnet         7.3-9     2015-02-11 CRAN   
 plyr         1.8.2     2015-04-21 CRAN   
 pscl         1.4.9     2015-03-29 CRAN   
 RColorBrewer 1.1-2     2014-12-07 CRAN   
 reshape2     1.4.1     2014-12-06 CRAN   
 rms          4.3-1     2015-05-01 CRAN   
 rsm          2.7-2     2015-05-13 CRAN   
 sandwich     2.3-3     2015-03-26 CRAN   
 UBbipl       3.0.4     2013-10-13 local  
 vcd          1.4-0     2015-04-20 local  
 vcdExtra     0.6-8     2015-04-16 CRAN   
 VGAM         0.9-8     2015-05-11 CRAN   
 xtable       1.7-4     2014-09-12 CRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LaTeX you could simply generate bibliography for all the packages using:

%% begin.rcode rubber, results = 'asis', cache = FALSE

% write_bib(file = "generated.bib")

%% end.rcode

You can put this after your \end{document} and add corresponding \bibliography{mybib,generated} entry. This way you could also reference them with usual \cite{}

Comment: I already do this, but via a latex command `\pkg{}` that prints the package name and also generates a `\cite{}` command.  But the colophon serves a different purpose--- to indicate in one place the package versions used in the text.